# Incorrect BigQuery results for OMIT RECORD IF query when Destination table is set

Tags: google-bigquery

I run the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM [fabrika21.master] OMIT RECORD IF NOT SOME (contact.phone = "9037777417")
```

with the following options:

**Destination table**: *some existing table*

**Write Preference**: Overwrite table

**Results size**: Allow large results

**Results Schema**: Flatten results

I have the following results:
[image: Query results]

As you can see, the returned record does not match the query.

When I replace star in the query with field, I have empty results:
[image: Empty results]

Strange, there is no "Query returned zero records." message.

And when I remove the destination table option, I have correct results:
[image]

I think it is a bug. If somebody from BigQuery team would like to help me, jobIds are:
bquijob_691c1514_1577669d359 (query with star and destination table)
bquijob_14e10ce2_157766b1a1b (query with explicit field and destination table)
bquijob_60d53244_157766c4d8e (query with explicit field and no destination table)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct, this is a bug in our display of the query results! While the actual query execution produced correct results, the web UI is caching previous results for the same destination table. In your case, an earlier query (perhaps `bquijob_2aa85566_15775c5cce4`) produced the results you later saw.

We'll address this immediately, but you can work around the problem by using the `bq` CLI program or refreshing your browser window between queries.

Thank you for the detailed post, it was a great help to diagnose the problem.

Comment: This should now be fixed in production. Thanks again for the report!